# using order by with union in inner select queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use order by clause in inner select queries with union operator i.e.

```
select colname from table where <cond1> order by colname 
union
select colname from table where <cond2> order by colname
```

I can use order by with the complete result but I want to have the results from first query ordered by and then the result of second query ordered by.

Please give me some suggestions upon it.

Comment: You have to take off first query's order by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should do... i guess

```
select colname,1 as OrderCol from table where <cond1> 
union select colname,2 as OrderCol  from table 
where <cond2>  
order by OrderCol
```

Comment: This resulting another problem as there are some records that satisfy condition 1 as well as condition 2,so this causing the repetition of these records as they are not unique now as OrderCol have made them different records.Can you please suggest the solution for it.

Comment: i don't understand why are you using union if you're selecting data from same table. Can't you write simple select stmt and put both the conditions there with OR. And use a distinct in the select stmt to ignore duplicate entries.

Comment: I have to use union as I need to give priority to that results which are coming from the first condition over the second condition.

Comment: You don't need to use Union for that. you can use case statement i.e.- select col1,col2, case when <cond1> then 1 when <cond2> then 2 end ordCol from tbl1 where <cond1> or <cond2> order by ordCol (upvote the comment if its helpful)

Answer (score 1):

the correct usage of `Order by` in `unioned` table is

```
select colname from table where <cond1> 
union
select colname from table where <cond2> order by colname
```

the explanation of the code above is, after the the two queries had been unioned, *it then **Sorts** based on the column name*. It **doesn't** sort the lower query first before the server union it with the first query. But there is an alternative for that, you need to wrap it in a subquery.

```
SELECT newTable.colname
FROM
(
    select colname, 1 as OrderThis from table where <cond1> 
    union
    select colname, 2 as OrderThis from table where <cond2> 
) newTable
Order by newTable.OrderThis, newTable.colname
```

if i got your idea correctly, you want to sort the columns first before you `union` the two queries right and maintaining their correct position (*first query results remains on top while the second query results remain below the first query*)

Comment: This resulting another problem as there are some records that satisfy condition 1 as well as condition 2,so this causing the repetition of these records as they are not unique now as OrderThis have made them different records.Can you please suggest the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

This may do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT colname  FROM table1 where <cond1> order by colname ) DUMMY_ALIAS1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT colname  FROM table2 where <cond2> order by colname ) DUMMY_ALIAS2
```